# Why stack unwind stops at CFRunLoopRunSpecific

Tags: ios, macos, stack, crash-reports

for example:below call stack

call stack unwind stop at CFRunLoopRunSpecific, why it does not unwind until main, even empty?

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36398848 __kill + 8
1   FrogFinder                      0x000b5034 0x69000 + 311348
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3447e980 __handleUncaughtException + 68
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x346ce2ca _objc_terminate + 122
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x338a33be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x338a344a std::terminate() + 14
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x338a481e __cxa_rethrow + 82
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x346ce22e objc_exception_rethrow + 6
8   CoreFoundation                  0x343d453e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
9   CoreFoundation                  0x343d439e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
10  GraphicsServices                0x30c58fc6 GSEventRunModal + 150
11  UIKit                           0x3785573c UIApplicationMain + 1084
12  FrogFinder                      0x0006a7e6 0x69000 + 6118
13  FrogFinder                      0x0006a7a4 0x69000 + 6052
```

Comment: The stack trace looks perfectly fine. Your question also doesn't make a lot of sense, please clarify further what your issue with this stack trace is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the backtrace you copied here does go all the way to main. What is your question exactly? If your question is: "why doesn't the exception go all the way to main?" Then the answer is that CFRunLoop installs a catch-all handler. I believe for both Objective-C and C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In `@try/@catch/@finally` blocks, exceptions are re-thrown at the end of a `@finally`.   This is typically okay for Objective-C exceptions as they capture the original failure point as internal state.  C++ exceptions don't (because any type can be thrown).  So here you're hitting an `@finally` inside `CFRunLoopRunSpecific` code that is maintaining stack unwind invariants while also unfortunately losing original context.

You can explore the differences for yourself by observing the behavior of raising regular `NSExceptions` vs C++ exceptions in a run loop source or `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`.